# Could somebody explain this code snippet please

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a connect four game, but I got stuck on how I'll reduce the column height when a player chooses a cell then drop. I tried to google it and found this I can't understand, could somebody explain it

Note: The solution I found https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100917/connect-four-game-in-java

```
for (int h = this.height - 1; h >= 0; h--) {
            if (this.grid[h][col] == '.') {
                this.grid[this.lastTop=h][this.lastCol=col] = symbol;
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: We can't explain this loop, because it is dependent on other earlier code which you did not include.  Please include enough information in your question so that it reasonably can stand on its own two feet.

Comment: ^^ This is extremely hard to answer without being able to know anything else about your grid array, height, lastTop, lastCol, and symbol variables

Comment: I can tell you that it's a loop backwards, from top to bottom. It searches from the stop of the column down until it finds a cell that contains "."; it then sets that cell to be `symbol` and at the same time records where it found this cell in `lastTop` and `lastCol` (the `lastCol` implies an exhaustive search). Given that the location has been recorded, searching seems like a redundancy - just increment `lastTop` and done.

Comment: @ScaryWombat not really - it's just recording where it found the "." cell and setting it to a value at the same time. It's very idiomatic C...

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `this` anywhere in your code if it's in the same class anywhere. It can be omitted completely unless you have another local variable with the same name which would be strange.

Comment: @faris some people like to prefix `this.` to indicate a field rather than a variable. It's like those people that prefix fields with `_`. I'm not saying that it's a brilliant idea (it's not), but that I've seen this in code before.

Comment: @BoristheSpider sorry but I can't see the light here, `if (this.grid[h][col] == '.') `  will resign the top one as it starts from the top, why it doesn't start from the bottom is it should fill the bottom first, actually that is the main purpose of the question

Comment: Your `h` is initialized to `this.height - 1`, which is at the bottom (two-dimensional arrays normally consider `0` to be the topmost element). So to me it does seem like it loops from bottom to top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop updates the grid which represents the board a.k.a the playground.
It simply puts the symbol which represents the current player into the column at the height which is still empty (empty is represented by a dot).

As you can see the grid is a 2 dimensional array which first dimension is the height.

`this.grid = new char[height][];
 for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
     Arrays.fill(this.grid[h] = new char[width], '.');
 }`